# how to name an image with current date and time using java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, bufferedwriter

I have been trying to name an image with current date(i.e.., D://01_03_2015.png) and save it to a location in my memory. But this code given below is returning null value when checked for the Exception in the catch block. I don't know where I went wrong. But i am getting the output when I have initialized the string as `string date1 = "D://output.png";`. Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

```
try
{
BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
{
 for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
{
    int rgb = r[y][x];
    rgb = (rgb << 8) + g[y][x]; 
    rgb = (rgb << 8) + b[y][x];
    image1.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
 }
}

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String today = dateFormat.format(date);

String date1 = "D:\\"+today+".png";
File outputFile = new File(date1);
ImageIO.write(image1, "png", outputFile);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "returning null value when checked for the Exception in the catch block"?  I don't see any catch block in your code snippet.

Comment: sorry. I forgot to mention them in the code snippet. I have added them now

Comment: But when I tried to use output.png as mentioned above I am able to get the output, but my requirement is that name of the image should be current date/ time.

Comment: So is the code getting to the catch block?  And what is being printed?  (By the way, `e.printStackTrace()` would give you more information than just printing `e.getMessage()`).

Comment: You know that in Java, when you put \\ in a string literal, it becomes just a single \? For two backslashes, you need to write \\\\.

Comment: @RealSkeptic True that.  But presumably, OP is running this in some variant of Windows, and actually wants the filename to be `D:\01_03_2015.png`.

Comment: Yes I have tried to add \\\\ slashes but same error, null

Comment: @DavidWallace Could be, but since he said it was working with the literal `"D://output.png"`, I was assuming (a) that the backslashes and slashes are exchangeable on Windows, and (b) that he wanted two of them.

Comment: So, put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block, and let's see the stack trace.  Otherwise, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for the clarification, can you help me in finding out where I went wrong?

Comment: YES.  If you'll give us the stack trace.

Comment: e.printStackTrace() is giving error void type not allowed here.

Comment: Just put `e.printStackTrace();` by itself between the curly braces of the `catch` block.  Don't try to use it inside any other method call.

Comment: Well it is showing blank screen, which means I guess no error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71980/discussion-between-user3364490-and-david-wallace).

Comment: And is the file there?

Comment: I am getting the output when I try to give it as String img_name = "D:\\output.png" 
String img_name = "D:\\"+current_date+".png" is not working

Comment: `current_date`?  or `today`?  Your comment says something different from your code snippet.

Comment: Sir, today is the string i have delcared in my project. To make thinks clear in the comments I mentioned as current_date as it is understandable.

Comment: Sir, sorry I sorted it out. I made a mistake. File outputFile = new File(date1,"true"); This is what I have given in my code. I removed true from that statement and image is getting saved. Thank you for helping me .